# Foundation zurb nav bar

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation, nav

I'm having problems making the sticky nav function work properly :(

What I want my nav bar to have/do is have the "menu" function and label on the left and a "telephone icon" icon on the right that will allow someone to make a call straight to me.

The other thing the nav is doing that I can understand is hiding itself behind the first picture on the page.

If anybody can help it would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>ABC</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css">
    <script src="js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js"></script>
    <!-- Included JS Files -->
    <script src="js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- START Navigation -->
    <div class="contain-to-grid sticky"> 
    <nav class="top-bar">
    <ul class="title-area">
    <!-- Title Area -->
    <li class="name"></li>
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>MENU</span></a></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="toggle-topbar call-icon"><a href="tel:1234567"><img src="img/75-phone.png" width="20" height="20"></a></li>
```

```
    <!-- Right Nav Section -->
    <ul class="right">
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li class="has-dropdown"> <a href="#">Services</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li class="divider"><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li class="divider"><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li class="divider"><a href="#">3</a></li>
      <li class="divider"><a href="#">4</a></li>
      <li class="divider"><a href="#">5</a></li>
      <li class="divider"><a href="#">6</a></li>
      <li class="divider"><a href="#">7</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </section>
    </nav>
    </div>

    <!-- END Navigation -->

    <!-- START Mobile logo -->
    <div class="row">
    <div class=" small-12 large-12 columns"><img src="img/landing-page-tiles-logo.jpg"><center><h2></h2></center>
    <hr />
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END Mobile Logo -->

    <!-- END main content -->

    <script>  document.write('<script src=' +  ('__proto__' in {} ? 'js/vendor/zepto' : 'js/vendor/jquery') +  '.js><\/script>')  </script>

    <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>


    <script>$(document).foundation();  </script> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If these two pieces of code are displayed consecutively, your Right Nav Section is positioned within the `<ul class="title-area">` tag. Close this list to allow your `<ul class="right">` list to be displayed in its regular position.